# Select dropdownmenu selected item

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I was wondering if anyone could advise me a little. I am attempting to use JQuery to select my dropdown item by a given value. Here is what I have

```
var myVar = document.getElementById('<%= hiddenID.ClientID %>').value

    if (myVar != "") {
        var val = $("select[name*=drpDescription] option").filter(function () {
            return ($(this).val() == myVar)
        });

        $("select[name*=drpDescription]").val(val.val());
    }
```

The above code snippet does get the correct option based on it's value matching my hiddenfield value. What I can't do is get my dropdown to display it as the selected item. I wondered if anoyone has any advise on where I am slightly missing the point.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the value by passing it as parameter in `.val()` with select elements selector:

```
$("select[name*=drpDescription]").val(myVar);
```